# My object's isKindOfClass executed with unexpected answer

Tags: objective-c, iphone, class

I've been trying to get this script print out the one of the two types of object that was inserted. However, it always prints both types while only one thing is inserted. There are two classes, VKJItem and VKJBox. VKJBox is a subclass of VKJItem.

This is the main.m:

```
VKJBox *box1 = [[VKJBox alloc] init];
VKJBox *box2 = [[VKJBox alloc] init];
[box1 addItem:box2];
```

and this is the implementation of my VKJBox's addItem method:

```
if ([item isKindOfClass:[VKJBox class]]) {
    NSLog(@"BOX");
}

if ([item isKindOfClass:[VKJItem class]]) {
    NSLog(@"ITEM");
}
```

The problem is that the script prints both BOX and ITEM to the console.

Comment: It's a class that I created previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VKJBox is a subclass of of VKJItem and therefore VKJBox is *a kind of* VKJItem and *a kind of* VKJBox.

**-isKindOfClass:** is used to determine whether an object is an instance of a class or an instance of a class which inherits from the class.

For example:

isKindOfClass[UIView class] will be true for UIImageView, UILabel, etc.

Use the **-isMemberOfClass:** to check if the object is an instance of the specified class exactly.

Comment: so how do you differentiate the two?

Answer (score 0):

On of your Classes must be a subclass of Other.

```
isKindClass:
```

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.

```
isMemberOfClass:
```

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of a given class.

You need to use `isMemberOfClass`

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass:)